# paired t-test tests on multiple datasets for two classifires comparison

Tags: matlab, testing, neural-network, classification, static-analysis

I want to apply paired t-test test on the accuracy results from two classifiers on multiple datasets, to determine if the differences are significant.

The accuracy results for the 2 classifiers are:

```
x = [97.09 77.72 80.32 77.33 81.77 95.58 92.13]
y = [96.2 72.4 77.5 74.6 88.98 92.7 72.4]
```

I did the test on Matlab using the command:

```
[h,p] = ttest(x,y,'Alpha',0.05)
```

But the hypothesis failed to reject and give me  `h = 0` and `p = 0.2493`. 
There is a clear difference between the two classifiers why it is rejected?

Comment: According to the t-test the null hypothesis is not rejected at the 5% significance level. What exactly is your question here? If you expected a different result, please show your reasoning for that.

Comment: The null hypothesis assumes that there is no difference between x and y, by doing the t-test I expected the null hypothesis will be rejected because clearly there is a difference between x and y and I have to show it in my study by using statistical tests, but it shows the opposite why?

Comment: I don't understand why you claim `x` and `y` are clearly different. Intuition often does not match up well with actual statistics. As indicated by the test, the difference between the two is not statistically significant.